# Use resources(like jar files) of a github repo in another repo using github actions?

Tags: java, git, github, github-actions, artifactory

I have two repositories and Repo A and Repo B and I am using GitHub actions in both repositories. Repo A creates some jar files which are required to run Repo B.

build.yml file of Repo A

```
name: Repo A
on:
  pull_request:
  push:  
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: 'PREP - GitHub context'
        env:
          GITHUB_CONTEXT: ${{ toJson(github) }}
        run: echo "$GITHUB_CONTEXT"

      - name: 'SETUP - Checkout PR branch'
        if: github.event_name == 'pull_request'
        uses: 'actions/checkout@v2'
        with:
          ref: '${{ github.event.pull_request.head.sha }}'

      - name: 'SETUP - Checkout Branch Code '
        if: github.event_name == 'push'
        uses: 'actions/checkout@v2'
        with:
          ref: '${{ github.ref }}'

      - name: 'SETUP - JAVA JDK 1.8'
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: 1.8

      - name: 'SETUP - Cache Gradle packages'
        uses: 'actions/cache@v2'
        with:
          path: '~/.gradle/caches'
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-gradle-${{ hashFiles('**/*.gradle') }}
          restore-keys: ${{ runner.os }}-gradle

      - name: 'BUILD - Code Build & Unit Tests'
        run: | 
          sudo ./gradlew build
```

Repo B has a similar build.yml file

It becomes easier when these repositories are build in local, it uses .gradle and .m2 of local to get those jars in external libraries.

Here I am not able to figure out how to use jars from repo A in Repo B because each job in a workflow executes in a fresh instance of the virtual machine.

I came up with one solution to write a few lines to clone and build Repo A in the build.yml file of Repo B but it would take a long time to build.

And I also want to know how Jfrog helps in this?

Answer (score 1):

You can upload the jars produced by the build from *Repo A* as a [build artifact](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/guides/storing-workflow-data-as-artifacts) then use the [download-workflow-artifact action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/download-workflow-artifact) step in *Repo B* to download it.